# WCF Rest Method - This webpage is not available

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have a few methods implemented in a service I am making using the WCF Rest Template as a base.

These methods are working fine and are returning Json data.

However, I implemented a method which returns a List of Objects, which continuously seems to give me a "This webpage is not available" error.  I have no idea how to debug this or what may be the cause.  Does anyone have any advice?

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetCars/{TypeId}", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public List<Car> GetCars(String TypeId)
{
    CarFilter carFilter = new CarFilter();

    carFilter.requestType = "product";
    carFilter.numberOfCars = -1;// Convert.ToInt32(numberOfCars);
    carFilter.carIdTo = -1;//Convert.ToInt32(carIdTo);
    carFilter.carIdFrom = -1;//Convert.ToInt32(carIdFrom);

    return CarDataAccess.GetCar(Convert.ToInt32(TypeId), carFilter);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which URL are you browsing to? How is the service hosted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to check. First, see if this is a KnownType issue by adding the [ServiceKnownType] attribute:

```
[ServiceKnownType]
```

Also, pre-.NET 4.0, if this is WCF, you still need your `OperationContract` attribute on the method. Try this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetCars/{TypeId}", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public List<Car> GetCars(String TypeId)
```

Comment: Starting with .NET 4.0 you don't need the `[OperationContract]` attribute anymore, only `[WebGet]` is enough.

Comment: Okay, then the Pluralsight video I watched today is old. :) I guess we need GW to tell us which .NET version he's using...

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0.  Thanks for your suggestions!  I think it looks like I have found the solution, but if there are any better solutions, I would definitely be open to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it wasn't apparent from the code snippet I posted. I didn't even think of it at the time, but the Data being passed back is passing inherited objects of type Car (example: SportsCar, Van, etc.)

I had to prepend the tag: [ServiceKnownType] for each of all the inherited types that could be returned and it looks like it is working.  Does anyone know if this is a valid solution?

Comment: That's a valid solution, but a brittle one IMO. If you google, there are alternative options.